# update U V data for matplotlib streamplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

After plotting streamlines using 'matplotlib.streamplot' I need to change the U V data and update the plot. For imshow and quiver there are the functions 'set_data' and 'set_UVC', respectively. There does not seem to be any similar function for streamlines. Is there any way to still updateget similar functionality?

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, because if you change the vectors, it would need to re-compute the stream lines.  The objects returned by `streamline` are a line and patch collections, which know nothing about the streamlines.  To get this functionality would require writing a new class to wrap everything up and finding a sensible way to re-use the existing objects.

Comment: A dirty workaround would be setting the visibility of the arrows and lines to 0 and then plotting the new streamlines. Will try if that is fast enough, since speed is an issue.

Comment: Works for the lines, but not for the arrows.

Comment: An improvement over your current workaround, if you only have the streamplot on your axes object, is to call `ax.cla()`, and then call `ax.streamplot(U_new, V_new)`.

Comment: At least as of 2022, `ax.streamplot(U_new, V_new)` does not work. It does require `positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is no, because if you change the vectors, it would need to re-compute the stream lines. The objects returned by streamline are a line and patch collections, which know nothing about the vectors. To get this functionality would require writing a new class to wrap everything up and finding a sensible way to re-use the existing objects.

The best bet is to use `cla()` (as suggested by dmcdougall) to clear your axes and just re-plot them. A slightly less drastic approach would be to just `remove` the artists added by `streamplot`.